# Python 3 LDAP3 - Connect to AD with user from a different domain

Tags: python-3.x, ldap

In Python 3, using the LDAP3 module, is it possible to connect to an AD using a user that is from a different AD?

I tried to set the connection string to use the account in Domain2, in order to connect to Domain1, but it's not working, I'm getting an error stating that the credentials aren't valid, even though they work when I try to connect to Domain2, using that same account.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mailer.py", line 47, in <module>
    conn = Connection(server, domain["connection_string"], domain["password"], auto_bind=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 321, in __init__
    self.do_auto_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 349, in do_auto_bind
    raise LDAPBindError(self.last_error)
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPBindError: automatic bind not successful - invalidCredentials
```

Is this possible at all, or does LDAP3 connections only works with users from the same domain?

Edit:

This is what I'm trying to use to connect when I get the error message above.

```
server = Server(domain1.example.com)
conn = Connection(server, "CN=BindAccount,OU=Users,DC=domain2,DC=example,DC=com", '#Password1', auto_bind=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

With ldap3 you can bind to any ldap server, there are no restrictions related to the Active Directory domain. Actually, LDAP is not aware of AD at all. Probably you are providing wrong credentials.

Comment: I doubt I'm providing the wrong credentials, because they work when I try to connect to Domain2 (domain2.com), but not when connecting to Domain1 (domain1.com). The connection string I use has a user_dn that points in Domain2, and not Domain1. I'll edit my post for an example.

Comment: You are creating a Connection with a user from domain2 but the Server is pointing to domain1. I think you must use a Server object that points to domain2.

Comment: Looks like this puts me on the right track (because I don't get any error when running conn.search()), however, nothing is being returned when I'm running a search. I'm trying to see where the problem is.

Comment: So I did some tests manually in the python3 interpreter, and whenever I try to run a search in that domain, even though I look for every person, or a specific user, nothing is being returned. However, it works for the 2 others domains I tried it in. The only major difference I can think of is that the domain that isn't working is part of another AD forest, it isn't in the same forest as the two other domains. Can this have an impact?

Comment: That was it. The search works (it returns something) if I bind to the server using a user from that domain, but it doesn't if I bind to it using a user from another domain (a domain that is part of a different AD forest). Is that expected behavior, or a bug?

Comment: When you don’t bind correctly to the server the search runs in “anonymous” mode. It doesn’t return any error, but the response is based on the server configuration, usually you don’t get any data back.

Comment: I'll do some more testing on Monday once I get back to the office. The response was empty, however the request returned information from the server, but different than the information I get from a successful bind.

Comment: I just did some more testing, and the bind is successful, since I'm using the same user (in Domain2) for the searches on both domain (Domain1 and Domain2), but only the search from Domain2 returns any results. Would you prefer that I open an issue on the ldap3 GitHub for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you connect to domain1, you can still search for domain2. E.g. if the domain is

```
DC = 'dc=domain,dc=example,dc=com'
```

you can still

```
conn.search('dc=example,dc=com', query)
```

to get results from all subdomains of example.com.